# Prob with facebook share and like when using oauth.io

Tags: javascript, facebook, oauth

I am using oauth.io for facebook sign. Now I want to add facebook share and like btn but they are not working directly because I have set the APP Domine as 'oauth.io' . I am using below code for facebook share but it say the APP URL doesn't match with set URL for App.
Please help me to solve this prob.

Code:

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'share',
  href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
}, function(response){});
```

Answer (score 1):

It’s not related to oauth.io, check your configuration on your Facebook app. You probably just have to add your domain to the Facebook app, (you can add multiple domain in your Facebook app settings). You also can add another platform (as the iOS app for instance) or whitelist the URL in the Facebook app's advanced settings to authorize the like/share.

Comment: I think only one app URL is allowed per facebook app